# Prove that if $p \mid a-b$ then $p^{n+1} \mid a^{p^n}-b^{p^n}$

Tags: elementary-number-theory, prime-numbers, divisibility, congruences

I need help with the following problem, I don't know how to continue. Let $p$ be a prime. Prove that if $p \mid a-b$ then: $$p^{n+1} \mid a^{p^n}-b^{p^n}$$

At first I thougt the following:

$$p \mid a-b$$
$$a \equiv b\ (p)$$
$$a^{p^n} \equiv b^{p^n}\ (p)$$
But I don't know how to go from $\bmod p$ to $\bmod p^{n+1}$, or if there's a simpler way to prove it. Could you provide me with any hint or another way of thinking of this problem? Thank you.

Comment: The expression $a^n - b^n$ factorizes nicely.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I see that then I would always have in the expansion of $a^n - b^n$ a factor of $(a-b)$ which is divisible by p. How could I prove that this product would be divisible by $p^{n+1}$

Comment: Plug in $a^p$ and $b^p$ into that expansion instead of just $a$ and $b$.

Comment: The trick is that there are exactly $p$ summands in one of the factors of $A^p-B^p$, each summand being equal modulo $p$

Comment: I want to say Fermat's little theorem.

Comment: @James47 yes! but the problem was given before Fermat's little theorem so the idea is to find an alternate way

Comment: There is no need to assume $p$ to be prime.

Comment: Try to prove this first for $n = 1$. That is, assume that $a = kp + r, b = \ell p + r$ with the same $r$. Now look at at $a^p$ and $b^p$. Write this out using the binomial theorem and look for all terms that contain $p^2$. What is the remainder in each case? *This does not assume that $p$ is prime, as per darij's observation.*

Comment: @Hans What if I just say that my i.h is that $p^{n+1} \mid a^p - b^p$ and I try to prove it for $p^{n+2}$? Taking that $a^{p^n} - b^{p^n} = qp^{n+1}$ equals $a^{p^n} = qp^{n+1} - b^{p^n}$, I would then have to show that$a^{p^{n+1}} = (a^{p^{n}})^p = (qp^{n+1} - b^{p^n})^p$ is divisible by $p^{n+2}$.

Comment: @Gio - That's a good strategy, but the key idea is still missing. Why do you think the induction step will work?

Comment: @Hans using the binomial theorem from the third sum on I would have p to a power that would be divisible by $p^{n+2}$ ... but it's true that I would still be missing the first terms.  Am I right? How can I show that? and thanks!

Comment: What is the first term? Which powers of $p$ does it contain?

Comment: Now I see. For this to work what I have to prove is that $a^{p^{n+1}} - b^{p^{n+1}}= (qp^{n+1} - b^{p^n})^p - b^{p^{n+1}}$ is divisible by $p^{n+2}$. And using the binomial theorem everything seems to fit now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can prove this by induction. The main step is the following

**Lemma:** If $a \equiv b \mod rq$ for some $q, \, r$, then $a^q \equiv b^q \mod rq^2$.

**Proof:** Suppose $a \equiv b \mod rq$, that is $a = b + krq$ for some integer $k$. Then by the binomial theorem 
$$
a^q  = b^q + q b^{q-1}\cdot krq +  + \sum_{j = 2}^q \binom{q}{j} b^{q-j} (krq)^j = b^q +\ell r q^2 
$$
for some integer $\ell$. Therefore $a^q \equiv b^q \mod rq^2$.

Now to prove the statement, use induction. The base step $n = 1$ is done by using the Lemma with $q = p$ and $r = 1$.

The induction step works as follows: Assume $a^{p^n} \equiv b^{p^n} \mod p^{n+1}$. Thus the assumption of the Lemma holds with $q = p, r = p^n$. Apply the Lemma and obtain
$$
a^{p^{n+1}} = \left(a^{p^n}\right)^p \equiv \left(b^{p^n}\right)^p = b^{p^{n+1}} \mod rp^2 = p^{n+2}  \, .
$$
The proof is complete.